# How can I ensure all Selenium webdrivers spawned by my program are quit() on program termination?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

Is there any way to make sure that all new instances of webdrivers are terminated (i.e. some equivalent of driver.quit() is called on them) when my program terminates in any way? That is, to make sure that the new process will close even if I forget to add an explicit `.quit()` in the code, or if the program crashes/is otherwise unable to reach a `.quit()` call.

Edit:
Here is a possible solution I thought of, but I'm not sure if it works and unfortunately I can't test it myself right now. I could make a factory class to create drivers, and also store those drivers in a static list. And then add a shutdown hook that calls quit on everything in the list. I have no idea if this works because I've never used a shutdown hook before :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all obviously do not forget adding explicit `.quit()`. Always wrap `phantomjs` driver initialization into `try...finally` operator and perform `.quit()` in `final` block. This should give guarantee that all processes of `phantomjs` will be finished.

Generally speaking though there is no general way of controlling external processes of OS from JVM, as `phantomjs` starts internally new OS process. What you can do - [call from Java program OS-dependent command](https://blog.art-of-coding.eu/executing-operating-system-commands-from-java/) for finding and killing `phantomjs` processes. Say, for `ubuntu` it will be `pkill -f phantomjs`:

(something like, not tested though)

```
java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime().exec("pkill -f phantomjs");
```

Comment: Haha yeah I'll do my best to not be forgetful. Adding an extra system call to kill the process will probably work fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can also think of resorting to a managed way of browser instantiation and cleanup, so that your tests don't have to do it explicitly but they only use a webdriver instance that was created for them.

The easiest way of doing this would be :

- you first define the intent (i.e., a test wants a web browser) by creating a custom annotation,
- leverage a TestNG listener (you do mention Java, so am guessing you would be considering using some flavor of Test Runner such as TestNG or JUnit), wherein  you intercept test methods, check if they have your custom annotation and if they do, you instantiate a webdriver instance and push into a thread local variant, that your tests would just query. After the test method runs to completion, you would in your after invocation, cleanup the webdriver that was instantiated.

This way your tests don't have to manage browser instantiation and cleanup on their own and you also don't have to resort to platform specific ways of cleaning up browser binaries.

[This blogpost of mine](https://rationaleemotions.wordpress.com/2013/07/31/parallel-webdriver-executions-using-testng/), should help you get started.